# Problems executing a function only when the page is 100% loaded

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for some way to execute a certain function, only when the page is 100% loaded, I already tested the `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {` and the `window.onload` but both cause the function to be executed together with the page load. I know this, because the favicon continues to run until the function is finished running. Does anyone know how to do this sort of asynchronous functions in vannila js?

Page Code:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var noonce = 0;
  const minzeros = 5;
  const dataforjob = "dfgfdgsdfg";
  var jobstatus = false;
  var verify = "";
  for (var i = 1; i <= minzeros; i++) {
    verify = verify + "0";
  }
  while (!jobstatus) {
    const block = sha256(dataforjob + noonce);
    const stringfortest = block.substring(0, minzeros);
    if (stringfortest == verify) {
      jobstatus = true;
    } else {
      noonce++;
    }
  }
  console.log(noonce);
  console.log(sha256(dataforjob + noonce));
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

div.topHeader {
  display: flex;
  background: #f5811e;
  padding: 5px;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div.topHeader i {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
}

div.topHeader p {
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #FFF;
}

div.pageContent {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
}

div.pageContent .imageContent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
}

div.pageContent .textsContent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 48%;
}

.mainTitle:not(:nth-child(1)) {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mainTitle:nth-child(1) {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div.redirectionBox {
  background: #44b8ab;
  border: 1px solid #009c77;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 8px;
}

div.bodyContent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

div.header {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #ebebeb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-sha256/0.9.0/sha256.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title>NetSafe - Device Check</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bodyContent">
    <div class="topHeader">
      <p>NetSafe</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pageContent">
      <div class="imageContent">
        <img src="#" title="Robot" width="250">
      </div>
      <div class="textsContent">
        <div class="texts">
          <div class="redirectionBox">
            <p>Estamos a realizar algumas verificações de segurança!</p>
            <p>Você será rederecionado automaticamente dentro de momentos para lojadozequinho.pt</p>
          </div>
          <p class="mainTitle">Olá, sabe porque está aqui?</p>
          <p>Você está a ver esta pagina, porque o administrador de lojadozequinho.pt, configurou o seu site para que todos os visitantes, passasem por uma verificação de segurança feita pela NetSafe.</p>
          <p class="mainTitle">Para que serve esta verificação?</p>
          <p>Esta verificação é para evitar que sejam efectuados ataques a pagina, utilizando bots.</p>
          <p class="mainTitle">Como é feita a verificação?</p>
          <p>O processo de verificação obriga o seu computador a resolver um desafio criptografico, também verificamos a reputação do seu IP Publico com uma base de dados.</p>
          <p class="mainTitle">O que acontece após a verificação?</p>
          <p>Após a verificação é criado um token de acesso a pagina que têm uma validade previamente definida pelo administrador da pagina.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header">
      <p>O seu ip: 2001:8a0:fd51:2200:ac26:9160:cc19:6579 &#8226; O seu netSafe id: 698dc19d489c4e4db73e28a713eab07b &#8226; NetSafe é um serviço da IMM</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The `DOMContentLoaded` event happens when the DOM is fully parsed, but external resources are still loading.  The `load` event on the window only happens once all the external resources are loaded.  This excludes any extra resources that are added to the page dynamically afterwards.

Comment: *but both cause the function to be executed together with the page load* <-- No they don't. What ***exactly*** is the problem with having the function run as a callback to the `load` event?

Comment: Thanks, the window load event works!

Comment: Oh ok, and you wrote in the question that it didn't work? What changed?

Comment: I tried the wrong method window.onload = function () {}, I don't know why it didn't work, but window.addEventListener ("load", function (event) {} already did

Comment: It should also work... window.onload = function(){} should also work :)

Comment: Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Comment: Now I have another problem, the user cannot interact with the page, until the function finishes processing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With window.onload event nothing will happen until everything is loaded.

```
window.onload = function(){ ... }
```

The `load` event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading.